# changing python runtime maximum recursion limit

Tags: python, automated-install, supervisord

I am trying to install supervisord on a ubuntu ec2 server. When running easy_install I get the following error:

```
> easy_install supervisor
...
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I know how to change the max recursion depth in a python script using sys.setrecursionlimit() but how do I change it for the runtime environment?

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/bin/easy_install` is a python script. Can you not just add a line to set a new value after the import sys line ?

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'setuptools==0.6c9','console_scripts','easy_install'
__requires__ = 'setuptools==0.6c9'
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1200)
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
sys.exit(
   load_entry_point('setuptools==0.6c9', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
)
```

Comment: I tried that, up to 5000. Is there a limit to how high the limit can be safely set?

Comment: I don't know - on the (non EC2 ) Ubuntu systems I have to hand I have to set the value as lw as 50 to see the error you get.